# How to check Status of email alert in the scheduled workflow

Tags: administration, admin

Lets say one example  Emails should be send to a no of users which is scheduled in workflow.Once email is sent how to check the status that whether the email is sent or not to all the users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use email logs to check the status of the emails.

You can access this by navigating to Setup>Monitor>Logs>Email Log Files.

The field "Mail Event" indicates the final email event in the mail server.

you can check the below links for the same.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=email_logs_format.htm&type=5

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=email_logs.htm&type=5